# How to get an index of element in vector?

Tags: notation, vectors

Suppose we have a vector:

$$a=(a_1,...,a_n)$$

What is the simplest way to define (using mathematical notation) a function which returns an index of given element?

Example: 
$$a=(10,20,30,30)$$
$$f_a(30)=3$$

Comment: This seems rather as a programming language construct than a mathematical function. For instance, in your example, why $f_a(30)=3$ and not $f_a(30)=4$ or even $f_a(30)=\{3,4\}$? And what should the function return if no element matches the argument? So to properly define such a function you should resort to some odd set-theoretical construct, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031803/vector-notation-for-not-including-index?rq=1